# Does Assembly.Load also load its references?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly");
```

Will the above also load all the references/dependencies "MyAssembly" needs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; references and types are loaded on-demand as they're required. The specific rules used for locating an assembly can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx).